# Can't insert a Web Forms For Marketers form because there are no Placeholders

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, web-forms-for-marketers

We are trying to fix an old issue with our Web Forms for Marketers module (I think it is 2.2, but I don't know how to tell) in Sitecore 6.4.1 running .NET Framework 2.0. I am having trouble even adding a form to an item. I am making an assumption that I should be using the "Insert Form" button in the presentation tab of my item.

When I click that button I get a wizard that goes fine until it tells me the following: "There are no allowed placeholders in order to insert a new form."

Ignorning the error's grammar issue for a moment, I assume it is telling me that there are prequisites for an item to allow it to work with a form. I looked around and thought that maybe the problem in this issue was related:

[Cannot get a Sitecore form to display in a placeholder (Web Forms for Marketers module)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517858/cannot-get-a-sitecore-form-to-display-in-a-placeholder-web-forms-for-marketers)

So I made sure a Form was in my template. It is there now, but throws a "value cannot be null" exception in the logs when I click "edit" on the Form item in the Device Editor.

[image: Screenshot of Sitecore making me want to punch myself.]

I have a Placeholder Setting as well since I have read that I need that for some reason. It is named "form" and the Settings Item is /content.

Am I missing a perquisite? Do I need to reinstall the module?

Comment: Does the placeholder setting you have actually list the "Form" component under **Allowed Controls**?

Comment: The suggestion Mark Ursino does is essential (to be able to place a form using the Insert Form button). Verify this by looking @ Placeholder settings and see if you have one defined for your "content". On Allowed controls add the Webforms Rendering. A form could normally also be manually place by adding a Form rendering and setting it's datasource to the correct Form.

Comment: @MarkUrsino Where are the "Allowed Controls"?

Comment: On my system, it's under Layout --> Placeholder Settings --> [SiteName]. You'll see an icon for each content item (e.g. body, content, sidebar). Each of those has an Allowed Controls section (in its Data category).

So, find the one where you want to allow a form, choose Edit, then drill down (Layout --> Renderings --> Modules --> Web Forms for Marketers), select the Form item from the All pane and press the right arrow button to add it to the Selected pane. Then save out.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you need to add a placeholder to the list of placeholders that are allowed to contain forms. The easiest way to do this is with the Restricting Placeholders application WFM installs. Login to the desktop, and under Sitecore -> All Applications -> Web Forms For Marketers -> Restricting Placeholders assign one or more where forms can live.

See http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web_forms_for_marketers_v2_reference_usletter.pdf, around page 7.

Comment: I messed with this before I posted the question and failed to mention it. I have the "content" placeholder settings in the Selected side of the "Restricting Placeholders" dialog box. Isn't that what I need to do?

Comment: Yes that should do it. However rereading your question it sounds like there's an error being thrown when you try to edit your manually added form rendering. That shouldn't occur that I know of; the form rendering is just a shim that stores a reference to the actual Form item that defines how the form looks. Could you post the stack trace of the null reference in your logs?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and after long time found that it was not supported to use uppercase letters or words in the keys for placeholders or when referencing them. So after I changed these keys to lowercase my problems simply was gone.