# Why must placeholders be lowercase?

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I've been curious about this for a while so I thought I would ask it here on stack. I was told to ***always*** lowercase my Sitecore placeholders by a consultant helping out on one of my projects.

I was new to Sitecore at the time, so I took it in stride and never really questioned it. However, as I've become more familiar with the system and how extensible and modular it can be, I really can't imagine why this would be a requirement..?

There doesn't appear to be any documentation on the subject, however, Sitecore themselves seem lowercase their placeholders in every example site I've ever seen.

The topic is [metioned a few times on the web](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/en/Developers/Articles/2011/03/Info-site-8-unified-page-editor.aspx) including right [here on stack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10690946/185749), however, the question remains: WHY?

Comment: Good question, I've never noticed that before....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *may* be referring to a specific version of Sitecore that had a bug in it. There is currently no requirement for using only lowercase. I suspect when Sitecore's dependency injection / layout engine runs, is compares the placeholder keys on the layout to the controls bound and ignores the cases when matching up placeholder keys.

Comment: Thanks, seems like a pretty trivial thing to ignore casing when comparing keys. Glad they fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

I isn't a requirement that I've ever heard about and on multiple projects I've had placeholders that aren't all lower case, typically I use camel casing for those.